# Groovy convert list of maps into a map

Tags: groovy

Hi I know this question has a thread already here but when I applied the answer provided on the thread it didn't work for me. So requesting for help with my exact problem below:
So I am trying to convert: [[xyz:346654], [xyz:343372]] to [xyz:346654, xyz:343372] in groovy. I tried to apply the solution provided on the thread which to use the collectEntries() method or sum() in groovy. But instead of getting [xyz:346654, xyz:343372] which is my desired result, I get [xyz:343372]. Can someone help figure out this please? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: All `Map` implementations require keys to be distinct, so your example of `[xyz:346654, xyz:343372]` isn't possible since the `xyz` keys would overlap (hence your output). Do you mean you want to take `List<Map<K, V>>` and make it a `Map<K, List<V>>` instead? E.g. convert `[[xyz:346654], [xyz:343372]]` to `[xyz: [346654, 343372]]`? Otherwise, what you're asking for isn't possible with the `Map` data structure.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. I forgot that map must maintain unique key. Can you suggest what to use instead of map to achieve [xyz:346654, xyz:343372]?

Comment: You probably want a map where the keys are strings, and the values are lists of strings ie: `[xyz:[346654, 343372]]`

Comment: Yea that worked for me. Thanks @tim_yates!

Answer (score 0):

[xyz:346654, xyz:343372] in groovy is the same same as [xyz:343372], because of non-unique key

```
println ( [xyz:346654, xyz:343372] )
```

prints [xyz:343372]